# Ionic Deep linker view does not update on browser back button event

Tags: ionic2

[image]I have a PWA built with ionic deep linker. I have done a demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-mee2ut?file=app%2Fcustomer%2Fcustomer.component.html where the browser back button doesn't work as expected.

```
Steps to reproduce
 1.In Dashboard page click on edit button.It will navigate to customer 
 page(see URL.It is changed to /Customer/CustomerId).
 2.In Customer page, you will see the customer info and other customers 
 list, there click edit from other customers list.This will open another 
 page.(see URL.It is changed to /Customer/CustomerId).
 3.Click on browser back button u can see that the URL is changed but the 
 view is not updated.
```

If I repeat steps 1 & 2 then click on nav back button instead of browser button then it works correctly.Both the URL and the view gets updated.

Is there something I am doing wrong because the browser back button does not work as expected or this is issue of ionic framework.

This is how i navigate between views

```
  EditCustomer(Customer: any) {
   this.navCtrl.push('Customer', { Id: Customer.Id, Name: Customer.Name });
  }
```

Can somebody please tell me a way how to resolve this issue?

Comment: do you have any fix for this ? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I saw your code in the above url, you are passing id as param but not the name so, that is the reason url is changing but data is not reflected i modified your code in app.module.ts file please replace this code in your app.module.ts file

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, {
      links: [
        { component: DashboardComponent, name: 'Dashboard', segment: 'Dashboard' },
        { component: CustomerComponent, name: 'Customer', segment: 'Customer/:Id/:Name' }
      ]
    })
```

Comment: Changed my links configuration but still, it is not updating the view.I have updated my code here in this link like you suggested https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nyw42s?file=app/app.module.ts . Changing above code did it work for you?

Comment: Can you please test it once properly, for me it is working fine, means the above link is working fine. please re verify it once and let me know

Comment: Hello, i rechecked it again.I am posted an image above which demonstrates the issue. In the image you can see url is Customer/2/Steve but the page shows info about Customer/4/Tod

Comment: Hi, If you open ionic app in mobile it doesn't have any browser button in your mobile, we can navigate back by using mobile back button. If you try the above code in mobile it will work fine

Comment: Answered separately , please have a look into that answer

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your app.module.ts with the following code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, IonicApp, App } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = 'Dashboard';

  constructor(private _app: App, platform: Platform, private _ionicApp: IonicApp,) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.setupBackButtonBehavior();
    });
  }

    private setupBackButtonBehavior () {

    // If on web version (browser)
    if (window.location.protocol !== "file:") {

      // Register browser back button action(s)
      window.onpopstate = (evt) => {
        //Navigate back
        if (this._app.getRootNav().canGoBack()) 
        this._app.getRootNav().pop();
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use something like this:

```
let randomID = this.makeId(5); // random string id
this.navCtrl.push('path', {
     eventID: eventID,
     instituteID: instituteID,
     randomID: randomID
}, {
     id: `path/${eventID}/${instituteID}/${randomID}`
});
```

This "id" seems to fix it, but if you can go to the same page, then it requires a "random" value to separate each visit to that page.

```
@IonicPage({
    name: 'path',
    segment: 'path/:instituteID/:eventID/:randomID'
})
```

It looks like, by default, it uses the name of the page as an id for that view. If multiple views have same id => issue when using browser back/forward. That's where the random comes in, to separate multiple instances of the same page.